# ServiceStack: nuget installation of OrmLite does not install all the pieces needed?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Installed package as per documentation and tried a simple query

```
db.SingleOrDefault<Customer>("Id={0}",id)
```

and got error

> Could not load type 'ServiceStack.Text.PlatformExtensions' from
>   assembly 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=3.9.26.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.":"ServiceStack.Text.PlatformExtensions"}

Is nuget definition missing pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing old NuGet packages. The current version for all ServiceStack NuGet packages (inc [ServiceStack.Text](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text/)) is v3.9.43.

Clean out your old NuGet packages and re-reference them again.

Comment: In my case ServiceStack.Text was just a dependency of ServiceStack.OrmLite. Somehow OrmLite was the correct version but .Text was not, I removed .Text manually from references (can't remove it from manage nuget packages because its listed as a dependency of .OrmLite). I then went to solution->manage nuget packages and added just .Text and it added the correct one that time. Not sure if this is the correct order but it worked in my case, no idea though why 3-4 of the packages were the right version and 1 was not.